# sql server - query one to many into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Sooo in our database, there is a table of prosecution cases with a prosecution ID and case code. There is another table of court updates (( It's a ***one-to-many relationship*** in the sense that one prosecution-case can have multiple court updates))

I am trying to create a report to show cases and their multiple court updates and I don't know how to write a query that has the following columns - Litigation Case Code & Court Updates.

This is the sample prosecution table

`╔════╦═════════════════════╗
 ║ID  ║ ProsecutionCaseCode ║
 ╠════╬═════════════════════╣
 ║  1 ║CASE158SG            ║
 ╠════╬═════════════════════╣
 ║  2 ║CASE688ZY            ║
 ╠════╬═════════════════════╣
 ║  3 ║CASE999SS            ║
 ║    ║                     ║
 ╚════╩═════════════════════╝`

This is the sample Court Update Table (CUid is court update Id)

`╔════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════╗
 ║CUid║ ProsecutionID║            UPDATE                   ║
 ╠════╬════════════ ═╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  1 ║    1         ║ 14th May - Judge wore pink          ║
 ╠════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  2 ║    1         ║ 13th May - Judge wore black         ║
 ╠════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  3 ║    1         ║ 12th May - Judge wore orange        ║
 ╠════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  4 ║    2         ║ 29th November - Judge was a no-show ║
 ╠════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  5 ║    3         ║ 19th January - Judge is cute lol    ║
 ╠════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  6 ║    3         ║ 1st January - Judge was mean        ║
 ╚════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════╝`

this is the report I am trying to create

`╔════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
 ║SNO ║ ProsecutionCaseCode ║            COURT UPDATE                ║
 ╠════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  1 ║CASE158SG            ║ 14th May - Judge wore pink             ║
 ║    ║                     ║ 13th May - Judge wore black            ║
 ║    ║                     ║ 12th May - Judge wore orange           ║
 ╠════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  2 ║CASE688ZY            ║ 29th November - Judge was a no-show    ║
 ╠════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
 ║  3 ║CASE999SS            ║ 19th January - Judge is cute lol       ║
 ║    ║                     ║ 1st January - Judge was mean           ║
 ╚════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝`

Comment: This is what SSRS is used for, or any other reporting solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2017; you can use the [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use code below

```
select u.ProsecutionID as sno,p.ProsecutionCaseCode  ,u.UPDATE as [COURT UPDATE] from prosecution as p inner join Update as u on p.id=u.ProsecutionID
order by u.ProsecutionID,u.CUid
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but you can use a sub-query within your select clause.

The hard part is concatenating multiple rows into one.  I've used [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server) for this.

Example:

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.ProsecutionCaseCode,
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            (
                -- Here we hijack the FOR XML clause to concatenate multiple values into one string.
                -- XML will append opend and closed UPDATE tags, as this is the column name.
                -- Replace functions strip these out.
                SELECT
                    [UPDATE]
                FROM
                    @CourtUpdate AS cu
                WHERE
                    cu.ProsecutionID = p.ID
                FOR XML PATH('')
            )
        , '<UPDATE>', '')
    , '</UPDATE>', CHAR(13)) AS [COURT UPDATE]
FROM
    @prosecution AS p       
ORDER BY
    p.ID
;
```

This approach uses a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).  These can hurt performance, as they force SQL Server to process row by row.  Ugh.

By default SSMS only shows the first line, in the results grid.  Press Ctrl + T to switch to *results to text* mode.  From here you can view the full results, without copying/pasting.

SQL Server 2017 includes a new function called [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql)  At the time of writing, this is pretty new.  Here's a (not tested) example:

```
-- SQL Server 2017 or higher.
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.ProsecutionCaseCode,
    STRING_AGG(cu.ProsecutionID,  CHAR(13)) AS [COURT UPDATE]
FROM
    @prosecution AS p   
        INNER JOIN @CourtUpdate AS cu       ON cu.ProsecutionID = p.ID
GROUP BY
    p.ID,
    p.ProsecutionCaseCode
ORDER BY
    p.ID
;
```

Much better.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server 2012 or higher**

```
SELECT PT.ID, 
        PT.ProsecutionCaseCode,
        CUT.UPDATE,
FROM ProsecutionTable AS PT
LEFT OUTER JOIN CourtUpdateTable AS CUT
    ON PT.ID = CUT.ProsecutionID
ORDER BY PD.ID,
         PT.ProsecutionCaseCode
```

I would strongly recommend avoiding doing an **INNER JOIN** in this case. With a **LEFT OUTER JOIN**, you will guarantee showing all ProsecutionCaseCodes, regardless of them containing an entry in CourtUpdateTable.